# Click event doesn't bind in second foreach in knockout

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

Why does my click event not work in the second foreach?

My html:

```html
<div class="row" id="menuBody" data-bind="foreach:categoryArray">
    <div class="outer col-md-2" data-bind=" attr:{id:id},event:{mouseover :$parent.mouseOverKnockout,mouseout:$parent.mouseOutKnockout }">
        <div class="inner col-md-12">
            <label class="label" data-bind="text:name"> </label>
            <div class="children" data-bind="css:{changeTopChildren: changeTopChildren}">
                <ul data-bind="foreach:$parent.items1" class="childrenUl">
                    <li data-bind=" text: name,attr:{id:id},click: $parent.selectLi" class="childrenLi col-md-12"></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

My script:

```
var modelCategory = function (id, name) {
    var self = this;
    self.changeTopChildren = ko.observable(false);
    self.name = ko.observable(name);
    self.id = ko.observable(id);

}
var modelProduct = function (id, name) {
    var _self = this;
    _self.name = ko.observable(name);
    _self.id = ko.observable(id);
    _self.selectLi = function () {
        alert("li");
        console.log("   selectLi");
    };
}
   var viewModelMenuBody = function () {
    var self = this;
    self.selectLi = function (tag) {
        alert("li");
        console.log("   selectLi");
    };
    self.categoryArray = ko.observableArray();  
    self.items1 = ko.observableArray();
    var temp = null;

    self.mouseOverKnockout = function (arg, e) {
        temp = arg;       
        for (var i = 0; i < self.categoryArray().length; i++) {
            self.categoryArray()[i].changeTopChildren(false);
        }
        arg.changeTopChildren(true);    
          $.getJSON("/Home/getChildrenForMenu", { id: arg.id }, function (rowProduct) {
            self.items1.removeAll();
            for (var total = 0; total < rowProduct.length; total++) {
                var temp = new modelProduct();
                temp.id(rowProduct[total].id);
                temp.name(rowProduct[total].name);
                self.items1.push(temp);
            }
        });
    } 

    self.mouseOutKnockout = function (arg) {

        if (arg!=null) 
     arg.changeTopChildren(false);

        //else
        //    temp.changeTopChildren(false);

    };

    (function () {
        $.getJSON("/Home/getDataForMenu", null, function (rowCategory) {

            for (var total = 0; total < rowCategory.length; total++) {
                var temp = new modelCategory();
                temp.id(rowCategory[total].id);
                temp.name(rowCategory[total].name);
                self.categoryArray.push(temp);
            }
        });
    })();
};

var viewModel1 = new viewModelMenuBody();
ko.applyBindings(viewModel1, document.getElementById('menuBody'));
```

Comment: You've posted *a lot* of code for such a small issue. Please trim down the code to only the minimal repro. It would also help if you tell us what "does not work" means (error? debug info? etc), and what you've tried and researched so far.

Answer (score 0):

All methods are defined within root viewmodel object. So `$parent.selectLi` call from the nested `foreach` binding won't work because `$parent` context refers to current item of the outer `foreach`.

Use `$root.selectLi` instead.

More info: http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/binding-context.html